# JDA attachment detection

Tags: java, maven, bots, discord-jda

so i ve recently started using JDA and i have no problem when detecting that a message was sent . But for some reason it doesn't work when it related to attachments .(yes ,i activated the intent in the discord bot settings ) and here is my code .

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return; // Ignore messages from other bots
        suppressContentIntentWarning();
        List<Attachment> attachments = event.getMessage().getAttachments();
        TextChannel textChannel = event.getChannel().asTextChannel();

        for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
            String fileName = attachment.getFileName();
            String fileExtension = attachment.getFileExtension();
            int size = attachment.getSize();

            if (attachment.isImage()) {
                textChannel.sendMessage("Image detected: " + fileName + ", size: " + size + " bytes").queue();
            } else if (attachment.isVideo()) {
                textChannel.sendMessage("Video detected: " + fileName + ", size: " + size + " bytes").queue();
            } else {
                textChannel.sendMessage("Other attachment detected: " + fileName + ", size: " + size + " bytes").queue();
            }
        }
    }
```

ps: i checked and attachments is always empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you call `suppressContentIntentWarning`, I would assume you did not do what the warning said. You have to enable the intent in the dev portal **and** in JDA.

See the [troubleshooting guide](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/#cannot-get-message-content-attempting-to-access-message-content-without-gatewayintent) for details.

Comment: Hey , so i did enable the intent in the dev portal but after verifying i did not enable it  JDA . thx a lot .   code for anyone having the same issue you need to add it when building your shardmanager ```builder.enableIntents(
                GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES,
                GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
                GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT
        );```